# Select a number of random rows based on one columan condition in matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have a table 'X' like this:
`name       value    score
joy        3          60
rony       8          50 
macheis    20         20
joung      2          80 
joy        8          3
joy        90         0
joung      4          78
machies    3          23
joy        7          99`

I want to select 2 random rows(with name, value, score) where the name is 'joy'. 
I applied something like this: 
`mnew = datasample(find(X.name=='joy'),2);` but it does not work! and gives  me the error: `Undefined operator '==' for input arguments of type 'cell'.` 
The rows should be selected randomly (with all columns values) where the name is `joy`.
Does anyone any other solution of this problem? how can i do it in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, but in order to check for the presence of a string within a  cell array of strings, you need to use `strcmp`, `ismember`, or another method for comparing a string to a cell array.

You probably also want to specify that you don't want to use replacement when calling `datasample` so you don't get the same row twice.

```
subx = X(datasample(find(strcmp(X.name, 'joy')), 2, 'Replace', false),:);
```

Comment: i still have the same error:
'Undefined operator '==' for input arguments of type 'cell'.'

Comment: @Hasan Sorry, I had a typo in there. Updated.

Comment: ok the correct way is `strcmp(X.name, 'joy')`, but why does it only return the index number? i need all columns values :( any solution?

Comment: @Hasan well that's what you had written in your original post. Updated now to return those rows.